# jquery- phalcon submit button click

Tags: php, jquery, phalcon

I am working with Phalcon framework. I have a `Tag::SubmitButton` in my view, and i want to create a JQuery `on-click` function. For example, when a user clicks on the `submit` button, show simple alert message. When I click on my submit button, nothing happens. Here is my view code:

```
<?php
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false);
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jquery.js");
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //alert($("#nesto").val());
            atr = $(".klasa").attr("id");
            alert("Id je: " + atr);

            $("#dugmic").click(function(){
                alert("Some message");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <h2>Basic example</h2>

    <?php echo Tag::form("xml/pretraga"); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <?php $opt = array('title', 'id'=>'nesto', 'size'=>'10');
            $buttopt = array('Show', 'id'=>'dubmic','class'=>'klasa');
        ?>
        <?php echo Tag::textField($opt) ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo Tag::SubmitButton($buttopt) ?>
    </p>
</form>
```

I would appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
The id is `'id'=>'dubmic'`, not `$("#dugmic")`
                    ^                  ^
                    |                  |
```

Comment: so what should I write in jquery, can you give me some example, please?

Comment: Whoot? You won't telling me you are not able to switch a `"g"` to a `"b"`, are you?

Comment: when I switch it it still not warking :) i don't understand, and i don't know why it didn't work at the first plase, becouse $("#myID").click(function() is regular jquery syntax, so i would like if you could give me some warking example, if you don't mind :)